# OpenGL version on Xcode - glfw vs sfml

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, sfml, glfw

I am learning `opengl` on my mac using both `glfw` and `sfml` and meet some hurdle on the `OpenGL` version.

When I run the code:

```
printf ("Renderer: %s\n", glGetString (GL_RENDERER));
printf ("OpenGL version supported: %s\n", glGetString (GL_VERSION));
printf("glsl: %s\n", glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
```

on `glfw`

```
Renderer: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100
OpenGL version supported: 4.1 INTEL-10.22.25
glsl: 4.10
```

on `sfml`

```
Renderer: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 6100
OpenGL version supported: 2.1 INTEL-10.22.25
glsl: 1.20
```

Is it my setting on the `xcode` project or that is the default framework setting? Is there a way I can change `sfml` to work with `OpenGL` 4.1 so that I get `glsl` 4.1 too?

`glfw` have this settings:

```
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
```

Do `sfml` have something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SFML you can specify the OpenGL version using `sf::ContextSettings`.

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.majorVersion = 4;
settings.minorVersion = 1;
settings.attributeFlags = sf::ContextSettings::Default;
```

Then you pass it to the `sf:Window` as you create it:

```
sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, settings);
```

Bottom line is that SFML needs a backwards compatibility context. Because internally SFML relies on some legacy OpenGL functionality.

So if you aren't using SFML for anything SFML specific. Then I recommend continuing to use GLFW.

Comment: By putting `settings` into the `window` does the magic. I use `sfml` for the interface graphic, which i find it hard to deal with that in `glfw`, at least at the moment.

Comment: You can use SFML with any OpenGL context version, but the 2.x version of SFML's graphics module uses the fixed function pipeline only (going to change with the upcoming 3.0). So as long as you do your own drawing, you shouldn't have issues.